# How do I extract a number from a row

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, numeric-data

```
31400     371    2946    3966   12378      82     185     206      46       1
```

I want to write a script that will always extract the second number from a script like the one above i.e. `371`. The number changes each time I run the script. Any ideas what bash command to use to extract just the number `371` but that number could be anything.

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly the sort of thing that `awk` is for:

```
$ ./yourscript.sh | awk '{print $2}'
371
```

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
cut -f2 file
```

presumed the data are Tab separated.

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
./yourscript.sh | { read a b c; echo $b; }
```